# How to display the output of a system command in browser exactly as in terminal

Tags: php, blast

I used php shell_exec to run BLAST command (biologcal sequence alignment tool) and outputs the result in **browser**. However, I am not able to format the result same like it displayed **when I run the same command in terminal** . I tried using methods like passthru() and exec(). Both of it doesnt work! In my case, output formatting is important as a small space can make the error (a portion is give below). Can anyone tell me how to  **display the result in browser as exactly which in command terminal**.

```
$cmd = "$blast -query /var/www/html/kim/blast/testing.txt -db /var/www/html/kim/blast/$db";
$result =shell_exec($cmd);
print_r ($result);
```

Part of my output looks like,

```
Query  707   TCAGACTTGAA  766
             |||||||||||
Sbjct  3632  TCAGACTTGAA  3691
```

Comment: Put it in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: I was not knowing the answer was very simple. Thanks@jeroen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep formatting identical, including spaces etc., you should use the `<pre>` html element. An example:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo $result;
echo '</pre>';
```

Just echo the raw result. Using `print_r` or `var_dump` would lead to formatting by PHP. The above example is the most raw formatting you can achieve, given you leave result untouched.

With CSS you can then style the `<pre>`. But make sure to use a MONOSPACE font so that shell formatting is kept.